# Using connection strings twice in web.config file; another for Nlog config

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I am using nlog in my project. My web.config looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SQL_ConnStr" connectionString="Initial Catalog=ConfigDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=mysqlserver; User ID=sa; Password=sa; Persist Security Info=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>
...
<nlog>
<targets>
  <target name="database" type="Database" dbProvider="sqlserver" **connectstring="Initial Catalog=ConfigDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=mysqlserver; User ID=sa; Password=sa"** commandText="INSERT INTO ...">
</target>
</targets>
<rules>
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="database"/>
</rules>
</nlog>
```

Two identical connection strings! My question is how to keep only one connection string?

Answer (score 20):

First add the add providerName attribute to connection string.  Then use connectionStringName instead of connectionString and refer to the connection string from the settings.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SQL_ConnStr" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="Initial Catalog=ConfigDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=mysqlserver; User ID=sa; Password=sa; Persist Security Info=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>
...
<nlog>
  <targets>
    <target name="database" 
            type="Database" 
            dbProvider="sqlserver"
            connectionStringName="SQL_ConnStr" 
            commandText="INSERT INTO ...">
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" 
            minlevel="Debug" 
            writeTo="database"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: I just want to add some important info. Of course he should use connectionStringName but also he should add providerName attribute to connection string (for example providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" for ms sql server). Without it NLog throws error: "Expecting non-empty string for 'providerInvariantName' parameter".

Comment: But where do i put the connectionStrings section. env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config"); throws an error for me that it cannot firnd the connection string name in the section

Comment: @flexxxit - that is a different question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882704/where-to-place-connection-string-in-web-config

Answer (score 7):

It should be possible with property ConnectionStringName of target element.

For ex:

```
<targets>
  <target name="database" type="Database" connectionStringName="SQL_ConnStr" commandText="INSERT INTO ...">
</target>
```

This will access the connection string from connectionstrings section directly.

Comment: somehow this one not working for me any idea?